# Cloudinary image uploading issue in rails - Internal Server error causing Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I am trying to implement the photo upload to the movie list model.
When submitting the form I am getting this error:

Started POST "/lists" for ::1 at 2024-02-08 10:59:08 +1100
Processing by ListsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "list"=>{"name"=>"tsubasa list", "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000010c3bc498 @tempfile=#Tempfile:/var/folders/mp/qwylt5g902v3ss7tn59cpy800000gn/T/RackMultipart20240208-19035-migmx5.jpeg, @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="Restaurant 2.jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name="list[photo]"; filename="Restaurant 2.jpeg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create List"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 6132)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 3)):

```
**** model ****
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :movies, through: :bookmarks
  has_many :reviews
  has_one_attached :photo

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

```
******** controller ****

class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @lists = List.where('lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search].downcase}%")
    else
      @lists = List.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      redirect_to list_path(@list)
    else
      render 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :photo)
  end
end
```

```
****** View *****
<div class="container w-50 py-3 border-bottom">
  <h1>New List</h1>
  <%= simple_form_for @list do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Classic Movies' %>
    <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-primary'%>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container w-50 py-2">
  <%= link_to " Go back Home", root_path, class: 'text-decoration-none'  %>
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate your help

I checked the Cloudinary config, the photo included in the strong params in the controller... nothing works :/

```
**. storage.yml **
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
  folder: <%= Rails.env %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

** config > environment > development.rb **
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary

Comment: When using the Rails SDK, the image file from the client side of the application must uploaded to the server side (and use the Cloudinary Ruby SDK - backend) to upload it the Cloudinary Media Library (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration). You can check out the [sample project at this link](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples).